# How `self` works in nested methods in ruby?

Tags: ruby

To see who is playing the role of `self` in `nested methods`, I tried the below code:

```
def test
  p "#{self}"
  def show
    p "#{self}"
  end
end
# => nil
```

As an effect, I got the two objects below:

```
Object.new.test
"#<Object:0x00000002212d78>"
# => nil
Object.new.test.show
"#<Object:0x00000002205330>" #<~~~ this is self understood
"" #<~~~ how this one came?
# => ""
```

But from the encoded numbers, I couldn't understand which class those objects belong to. And I tried the code below and got the respective `class` names.

```
Object.new.test.class
"#<Object:0x000000021ff3b8>"
# => NilClass
Object.new.test.show.class
"#<Object:0x000000020660b0>"
""
# => String
```

So can anyone help me to understand the concept of how the above code produced those `class` names?

***EDIT***

Here I tried to ask my question on more specific way:

```
def test
p "First level # => #{self}"
def show
p "Second level # => #{self}"
end
end
# => nil
Object.new.test.show
"First level # => #<Object:0x000000014a77b0>"
"Second level # => "
# => "Second level # => "
Object.new.test.show.class
"First level # => #<Object:0x0000000130ef70>"
"Second level # => "
# => String
```

***Why the `p "Second level # => #{self}"` statement `self` has `""` value?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object.new.test.show calls the show method in the Object.new.test object.

Object.new.test returns nil (as p returns nil), but at the same time it adds the definition of the show method to Object class.

As nil is of the class NilClass, which is a subclass of Object, nil has now show as a method, so you can actually call show in nil.

When you do Object.new.test.show is equivalent then to do

```
nil.show
```

When, within show, you do p "#{self}", you are actually printing nil.to_s

```
nil.to_s is ""
```

That explains that mysterious "" you see.

Answer (score 1):

It's rather straightforward:

```
def show
  p "#{self}"
end
```

returns `nil`, i.e. the `def` part, this is why the `test` method returns a `nil` object, an instance of the `NilClass`. Within the `show` method, you are doing `p "#{self}"` which will return a string object which is an instance of the `String` class.

Comment: I Thought OP wanted to know why the object ids were different, I was wrong, so I removed the down vote and added an upvote ;) Cheers.

Comment: @LoveConcept Think of it this way: copy the `show` method into irb, and you will see at the end `=> nil`, which means that the definition of the `show` method will "return" `nil`. The last statement in the `test` method is considered the `nil` returned from `show`.

Comment: Humm, now how the `string` and also I have edited my description. have you seen that?

Comment: `self` refers to the current object, which depends on your context. `p "#{self}"` is equivalent to saying `p "#{self.to_s}"` that is output you're seeing. Within `show` `self` is the outer function `test`, and `test.to_s` is equivalent to `nil.to_s` because it returns `nil`.  Also, I think you may be confused by the `.class` behavior because you are invoking it on the **returned** value, not the value passed to the `p` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
class FooBar
  def foo
    puts self.class
    puts self
    def bar
      puts self.class
      puts self
    end
    bar
  end
end


FooBar.new.foo
```

I got :

```
FooBar
#<FooBar:0x007fc413849818>
FooBar
#<FooBar:0x007fc413849818>
```

You got different results since you allocated different objects.

`self` returns the object where the method is defined in, even if it's a nested method.

Comment: I know `self` but just curious to know which made it to be and `NilClass` object and why `String` class? Can you tell me that with my code examples?

Comment: That's because p returns a String, and the definition of a new function returns nil, see @Candide answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using: `self.class.to_s`. SO wants me to enter extra characters, so [:

Answer (score 0):

We all know that - ***`self inside a method is always the object on which the method was called`***. So let's try and examine the truthfulness of that.

Let's see who is default `self` from the below code first of all:

```
m=self
# => main
m.class
# => Object
```

Okay, the default `self` is the object of `Object` class.

Just written the below code in more simplified way, from the description mentioned code,to highlight on the concept.

```
def test
p self.class
def show
p self.class
end
end
# => nil
```

Keeping in mind `self inside a method is always the object on which the method was called` called only `test` as below.

```
test
Object
# => nil
```

Yes, `Object` has been returned,on which the `test` has been called,that means the above statement is true.

```
test.show
Object
NilClass
# => NilClass
```

Calling to `test` also returns `nil` due to the block `def show;p self.class;end`.Now `nil` is an object of `NilClass`. Thus `show` method has been called on `NilClass` object. As result `self` is `NilClass`. Again the above statement holds.

With the above concept trying to reach to the actual goal with tiny steps:

```
def test
p "1. # => #{self}"
def show
p "2. # => #{self}"
end
end
# => nil

test
"1. # => main" #<~~ main is an object of class Object,on which test was called from IRB.
# => nil

test.show
"1. # => main"
"2. # => "    #<~~ nil("" means nil.to_s) is an object of Nilclass,on which show was called from IRB.
# => "2. # => "
```